# Float point numbers are not equal, despite being the same?

Tags: c, floating-point

The program below outputs `This No. is not same`. Why does it do this when both numbers are the same?

```
void main() {
    float f = 2.7;

    if(f == 2.7) {
        printf("This No. is same");
    } else {
        printf("This No. is not same");
    }
}
```

Comment: `float` representation is not necessarily the same as `double` representation.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Neither `f` nor the double precision literal `2.7` are equal to the exact value 2.7. The is an issue of representability.

Comment: Due to the discrete (steppped / incremental) nature of bits, there is always a float / double which can be written that lies between the two smallest steps.  So, the constant `2.7` might not actually be represented in binary as exactly `2.7`.  Also, since double has more precision than float, it would not equal bit-wise because the closest float to 2.7 is not as close as the closest double to 2.7.  Basically, when dealing with floats, you need to consider the error boundaries around the number.  Doubly so for float to double conversions and the like.

Comment: Type of `f` is `float`, type of `2.7` is `double`. First, in the initialization, `2.7` (of type `double`) is converted to `float` (losing some precision) and then the resulting `float` converted to `double` for the comparison. The two values (`(double)((float)2.7)` and `2.7`) may be different.

Answer (score 7):

> Why does it do this when both numbers are the same?

The numbers are not the same value.

`double` can represent *exactly* typically about 2<sup>64</sup> different values.
`float` can represent *exactly* typically about 2<sup>32</sup> different values.

2.7 is not one of the values - some approximations are made given the *binary* nature of floating-point encoding versus the *decimal* text 2.7

---

The compiler converts `2.7` to the nearest representable `double` or
2.70000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125
given the typical [binary64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary64) representation of `double`.
The next best `double` is
2.699999999999999733546474089962430298328399658203125.
Knowing the *exact* value beyond 17 significant digits has reduced usefulness.

When the value is assigned to a `float`, it becomes the nearest representable `float` or
2.7000000476837158203125.

2.70000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125 does not equal 2.7000000476837158203125.

Should a compiler use a `float/double` which represents `2.7` *exactly* like with [decimal32/decimal64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal64_floating-point_format), code would work as OP expected.  `double` representation using an underlying decimal format is rare. Far more often the underlying `double` representation is base 2 and these conversion artifacts need to be considered when programming.

Had the code been `float f = 2.5;`, the `float` and `double` value, using a binary or decimal underlying format, would have made `if (f == 2.5)` true. The same value as a high precision `double` is representable *exactly* as a low precision `float`.

(Assuming binary32/binary64 floating point)
 `double` has 53 bits of significance and `float` has 24. The key is that if the number as a `double` has its least significant (53-24) bits set to 0, when converted to `float`, it will have the same numeric value as a `float` or `double`. Numbers like `1`, `2.5` and `2.7000000476837158203125` fulfill that. (range, sub-normal, and NaN issues ignored here.)

This is a reason why exact floating point comparisons are typically only done in select situations.

Answer (score 1):

Check this program:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main()
{
   float x = 0.1;
    printf("%zu %zu %zu\n", sizeof(x), sizeof(0.1), sizeof(0.1f));
    return 0;
}
```

Output is `4 8 4`.

The values used in an expression are considered as `double (double precision floating point format)` unless a `f` is specified at the end. So the expression `“x==0.1″` has a double on right side and float which are stored in a single precision floating point format on left side.

In such situations `float is promoted to double` . 
The double precision format uses uses more bits for precision than single precision format.

In your case add `2.7f` to get expected result.

Comment: Using `%d` with the result of `sizeof` is undefined behaviour. Use `%zu`.

Answer (score 0):

The literal `2.7` in `f == 2.7` is converted to `double` that's why `2.7` is not equal to `f`.

Comment: Untrue. The issue here is that the *literal* 2.7 is taken as `double`.

Comment: @EJP; Agreed. Edited the answer.