# Why does this code print greater?

Tags: c, output

```
1)#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
float x=0.5;

if(x>0.5)
printf("\ngreater");
else
printf("\nlesser ");
return 0;
}
```

output->lesser

```
2)#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
float x=0.1;

if(x>0.1)
printf("\ngreater ");
else
printf("\nlesser ");

return 0;
}
```

output->greater
Why in the first case output is "lesser" while in the second one output is "greater"? What is the difference?

EDIT: I understood that 0.1 is not equal, but then why 0.5 is showing as equal?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082569/float-point-numbers-are-not-equal-despite-being-the-same/25082613#25082613 and also look @ http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparison-float-value-c/

Comment: `x` is a float ~ `0.10000000149011611938` while `0.1` is a double ~ `0.10000000000000000555`. `0.5` is exactly, so `x>0.5` evaluates to false

Comment: I think you're comparing float with double. Change to if(x>(float)0.1) and if(x>(float)0.5) and the result will be always lesser.

Answer (score 3):

I almost sure it's because you are comparing float and double.

There's an answer to why it is greater answered here : [0.1 float greater than double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292283/0-1-float-is-greater-than-0-1-double-i-expected-it-to-be-false)